# how to output paragraphs with spaces from a file using unix/linux grep/awk/sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have a file which contains the following logs

```
Get Authentication token from url
    1) should successfully return a token

  Get profile
    ✓ should successfully return a profile 

  Create a user profile 
    ✓ Should successfully create a new profile 


  Get a 400 Error when using invalid URL
    ✓ should return 400 status code )

  3 passing (9s)
  1 failing

  1) Get Authentication token from url
       should successfully return an access token:
     CypressError: `cy.request()` failed on:

https://testurl.com

The response we received from your web server was:

  > 400: Bad Request

This was considered a failure because the status code was not `2xx` or `3xx`.

If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option: `failOnStatusCode: false`

-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I basically want to just output everything below `1 failing` and I want it to stop at the dashed line. how can I do this using grep,awk or sed?

I have tried `awk '/failing/' RS="\n\n" ORS="\n\n" sample2` and `awk -v RS='' -v '/failing/' sample2` but all that outputs is `1 failing` and nothing else.

Comment: @anubhava please check the updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`, you may do this:

```
sed -En '/^[[:space:]]*[0-9]+ failing/,$p' file
```

or if you want to skip marker lines then use:

```
sed -En '/^[[:space:]]*[0-9]+ failing/,/^---*/{ //!p; }' file
```

Using `awk` you can use:

```
awk '/^-+/{p=0}; p; /^[[:space:]]*[0-9]+ failing/{p=1}' file
```

Comment: Note that the sed version will work with GNU sed but C escape sequences like `\t` are not standard. The bracket expression `[\t]` matches `\ ` or `t` in POSIX sed. The [awk spec explicitly extends ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04) to support them.

Comment: `[ \t]` worked on my BSD and gnu sed versions. To make it compatible with order POSIX sed versions one can use `sed -n '/^[[:space:]]*1 failing/,$p' file`

Comment: Indeed `[[:space:]]` is standard and works fine. I just tested again a simple `sed 's/[\t]/x/'` on FreeBSD 12.1 and I confirm that it fails to match tab characters (but it matches literal backslashes and `t`'s).

Comment: @anubhava how can I stop the output at the `-----------------------------------------------------------` line ?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '/\<1 failing/ {s=$0;found=1} {if(found && $0!=s) print}' file
```

will print:

```
1) Get Authentication token from url
       should successfully return an access token:
     CypressError: `cy.request()` failed on:

https://testurl.com

The response we received from your web server was:

  > 400: Bad Request

This was considered a failure because the status code was not `2xx` or `3xx`.

If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option: `failOnStatusCode: false`
```

---

The logic is that when the string we are interested in is found, `1 failing`, we set a flag to true (`found`) and we store the current line (`s`). awk will then iterate over all the lines in the file. We can check for two conditions. The flag found is true and that the current line is different than `s`. When the conditions are met, the line is printed.

Comment: Unfortunately `\<1` doesn't work in gnu-awk or BSD-awk for intended word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're really trying to do is:

```
awk 'f{print; next} /^[[:space:]]*[0-9]+[[:space:]]+failing[[:space:]]*$/{f=1}' file
```

i.e. print the lines **after** a line that is just `failing` preceded by any number and optional surrounding spaces. That's based on your text (emphasis on `below` mine) and code (which only tests for `failing`) at the end of your question:

> I basically want to just output everything **below** 1 failing ... I have
> tried `awk '/failing/' RS="\n\n" ORS="\n\n" sample2` and `awk -v RS='' -v '/failing/' sample2`

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) and [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) are tagged, using grep and  Perl-compatible regular expressions (where available, GNU grep at least):

```
$ grep -Pzo "(?<=1 failing\n)(.*\n)*" file
```

Consider widening the regex for `1 falling`if needed.